# No arrowheads and colour

Tags: plotting

I haven't been able to make this work; I want no arrowheads, but black vectors (segments). If I use

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    VectorStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3], Arrowheads[0], Black}}]
```

[image]

I get the arrowheads.

Comment: What version are you using?  I get no arrowheads in versions 9 and 11:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsLNe.png

Comment: @JasonB I am using Mma 10!

Comment: If you quit the kernel and run your code, do you still get the arrowheads?  If so, post the graphics output here also. I just tried this on 10.3.1 and it gives the same result.

Comment: @JasonB https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au5fo.png

Comment: I get no arrowheads using 10.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `"10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)"` I get the same result as the OP. In version 10.1 I get the correct result, so it appears the issue was fixed by then.

To remove the arrowheads in version 10.0, you can use

```
VectorPlot[{x, y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  VectorStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3], Black}}
] /. Arrow -> Line
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]